# How to grant execute on specific stored procedure to user

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, sql-grant

I have created some stored procedure on a specific schema.

In this stored procedure, I want to grant execute privilege.

So I wrote that :

```
GRANT EXECUTE ON PROCEDURE schema_name.proc_name TO 'user_name';
GRANT SELECT ON mysql.proc to 'user_name';
```

The problem is : My user can see every stored procedure.
I wish he could only see the procedure where he has the EXECUTE privilege.

Is there a way to achieve that ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6):

Yes... this works as expected if you don't grant the user the `SELECT` privilege on the `mysql.proc` table, either directly or indirectly, such as with `GRANT SELECT ON *.* TO ...`

Without `SELECT` permission on this table, a user can only see the existence of stored procedures and stored functions where they have other permissions, like `EXECUTE`.

Under the hood, the lack of `SELECT` on `mysql.proc` also prevents the user from seeing the procedures they don't have access to via the `information_schema.routines` pseudo-table.

You shouldn't need to `GRANT SELECT ON mysql.proc` to enable the user to execute procedures or functions... and if you do, then *that* seems like the question.

Comment: In fact, it seems that it's my plugin which caused the issue.
I'm using MySQLForExcel to allow users to interact with the DB.
You're right, without SELECT ON mysql.proc, I can call my stored procedures without problems. But MySQLForExcel doesn't allow it for some obscurs reason... 
**Unable to retrieve stored procedure metadata for routine 'truncate_t_qcms_lead_engineer'.  Either grant  SELECT privilege to mysql.proc for this user or use "check parameters=false" with  your connection string.**

Answer (score -1):

Problem solved.

In fact, To be able to execute stored procedure within MySQLForExcel, we need to SET the DEFINER of each stored procedure that we want to be called by a MySQLForExcel user.

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `procedure_name` $$
CREATE DEFINER=`user_mysqlforexcel` PROCEDURE `procedure_name`(param)
BEGIN
     Do smth as usual
END $$
```

[I found that here](http://dotnetfish.blogspot.fr/2011/03/unable-to-retrieve-stored-procedure.html)

Thank for the help.

Comment: Actually, that works for the wrong reasons and may have security implications.  The correct solution was probably in the original error message: you need CheckParameters=false in the ODBC connection string to disable the brokenness in ODBC that was causing the error.