# Why I can't see workbench mysql functions parameters even if I have execute permissions?

Tags: permissions, mysql-workbench

On workbench I connect to my Database, there I have defined some functions as superuser.
Then I set up a readuser that have execute permissions on these functions. 
But I don't want readuser to be able to alter those funcs.
When I connect using the readuser, he can list the functions in the schemas tree, he can also execute the function and see the results.

The problem is that he cannot right click on those functions and select on the menu

Copy to Clipboard>Function call

or

Send to SQL Editor>Function call

this is very unhandy since the readuser cannot see what are the parameters needed for the function to be executed.

Do you have any suggestion on how to workout on permissions (or else?) to resolve this?

Many thanks

Comment: So, you say, if a user has no alter privilege the copy-to-clipboard feature is not available (disabled menu entry?)? If so it might require some changes there and you should file a bug report (http://bugs.mysql.com).

Comment: no actually the menu entries are there and enabled, but nothing happens. No copy, no send to SQL editor of the string funcCall(param01 type, ...). i.e. readuser can only see (and execute them) the func names in schemas tree but don't know what are the requested params to call. So i wonder if there's some other option to tweak his permissions... Or if it's just a workbench client issue

Comment: Oh, then it's definitely a bug.

Comment: not a bug,  see my own answer below. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
GRANT EXECUTE ON PROCEDURE schema_name.proc_name TO 'user_name';
GRANT SELECT ON mysql.proc to 'user_name';
```

What was missing was the second line of GRANT.

This is similaer/duplicate of:

[How to grant execute on specific stored procedure to user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24493288/how-to-grant-execute-on-specific-stored-procedure-to-user)